# Mounted a windows file in ubuntu, can't access it through terminal

Tags: command-line, server, mount

So I am 95% sure I mounted the drive(files) that I wanted from a Windows server to ubuntu. I followed the tutorial on http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/22518/how-to-mount-a-remote-folder-in-ubuntu/ and I am given the option to unmount the folder I set up and am calling engineer.

I am trying to push my code onto a git repo on the server.  I cannot figure out how to access the files in what I mounted through the terminal.  Is there something similliar to the cd command to use in the terminal to access the server?  I don't know if this picture helps, but there are two drives mounted on computer which I can access 
fine.

However engineer is listed under network and i do not know how to access it in terminal.  When I hover the mouse over it smb::/192./engineering does appear.  But I cannot figure out how to access this.

[image]

Comment: Scroll down and read the _entire_ tutorial you linked to. It is explained quite nicely there.

Comment: have you just tried dragging the folder you want to access in the terminal, to the terminal? It does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drag the folder or file you want to access, to the terminal, and you will have the location to access it in the terminal.

Comment: I created a copy and put it in the file I wanted to.  Finally I have access to my git repo.   In Windows it would seem so obvious to do that.